# JQuery. Highlight table cells

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

On an HTML table, when a mouse is over a cell (TD), I would like to:

1. Add the css class "Highlight_TR_TH" to the cell's row.
2. Add the css class "Highlight_TD" to all cell on the same row
3. Add the css class "Highlight_This_Cell" to the cell itself.

Basically, I am looking to change the background color of this elements.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using css directly?

Comment: To be honest no ... But I didn't know I could do this using CSS. How can I do it?

Comment: for CSS: 
tr:hover {
  /** properties in Highlight_TR_TH */
}

tr:hover td {
  /** properties in Highlight_TD */
}

td:hover {
  /** properties in Highlight_This_Cell */
}

Comment: Yes you can pretty sure what @ArnelleBalane has put will do it.  Also I would use that method over jQuery as it will be faster due to no extra code needing to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('td').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('highlight_this_cell');
  $(this).parent().addClass('highlight_tr');
  $(this).parent().find('td').addClass('highlight_td');
},function(){
  $(this).removeClass('highlight_this_cell');
  $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight_tr');
  $(this).parent().find('td').removeClass('highlight_td');
}
);
```

`.hover()` takes two functions, the first one is executed on mouseover, the second on mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('Highlight_TD Highlight_This_Cell');
    $this.siblings().addClass('Highlight_TD');
    $this.closest('tr').addClass('Highlight_TR_TH');
},function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('Highlight_TD Highlight_This_Cell');
    $this.siblings().removeClass('Highlight_TD');
    $this.closest('tr').removeClass('Highlight_TR_TH');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J28he/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("Highlight_TR_TH");
  $(this).siblings("td").addClass("Highlight_TD");
  $(this).addClass("Highlight_This_Cell");
});
```

You can chain those method calls, just displayed them that way for more readability. 
If ever you wanted to remove the classes later on, you can use `mouseleave` with the same structure above to do it.

(Although I believe that pure CSS can do what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('Highlight_This_Cell').siblings('td').addClass('Highlight_TD');
        $(this).parent().addClass('Highlight_TR_TH');
    });
});
```